# TimeAgo Always appears as "Just Now"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't seem to understand what's going on, and why nothing's changing when it should change

```
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
    let timeAgo = timeAgoSince(date)

    print(timeAgo)
```

print (timeAgo) always appears as "Just Now" Any help I could get regarding this issue?

Here's my extension

```
public func timeAgoSince(_ date: Date) -> String {

let calendar = Calendar.current
let now = Date()
let unitFlags: NSCalendar.Unit = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfYear, .month, .year]
let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components(unitFlags, from: date, to: now, options: [])

if let year = components.year, year >= 2 {
    return "\(year) years ago"
}

if let year = components.year, year >= 1 {
    return "Last year"
}

if let month = components.month, month >= 2 {
    return "\(month) months ago"
}

if let month = components.month, month >= 1 {
    return "Last month"
}

if let week = components.weekOfYear, week >= 2 {
    return "\(week) weeks ago"
}

if let week = components.weekOfYear, week >= 1 {
    return "Last week"
}

if let day = components.day, day >= 2 {
    return "\(day) days ago"
}

if let day = components.day, day >= 1 {
    return "Yesterday"
}

if let hour = components.hour, hour >= 2 {
    return "\(hour) hours ago"
}

if let hour = components.hour, hour >= 1 {
    return "An hour ago"
}

if let minute = components.minute, minute >= 2 {
    return "\(minute) minutes ago"
}

if let minute = components.minute, minute >= 1 {
    return "A minute ago"
}

if let second = components.second, second >= 3 {
    return "\(second) seconds ago"
}

return "Just now"

}
```

Timestamp's value is 1604189555939 but timeago doesn't change any help? and thanks

Comment: Assuming that your timestamp is in the past, it is in _milliseconds_ since 1970...

Comment: Instead of printing `timeAgo` do `print(date)`, it discovers the issue immediately. And don't use the `NS...` stuff in Swift, there are native types.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timestamp in millisecond while Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp) take a seconds, so using below code will resolve your issue:

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp / 1000)
let timeAgo = timeAgoSince(date)
print(timeAgo)
```